# Are URL variables safe

Tags: php, variables, url

Are passing URL variables safe? Yes, I know they are out there in plain site for anyone to look up and see.... it's not a SSN or anything. I'm not talking HTTPS items, just passing a title and an email address....

For instance, let's say in the About Us page of a site, there's a list of employees.  Let's take "Jimmy" for example.  Jimmy has a bio and picture, and a [CONTACT JIMMY] button by his bio.  If someone clicks on [CONTACT JIMMY], it does the following :

```
<a href="contact.php?title=Jimmy&emailto=jimmy@mysite.com">
```

In contact.php, I check to see if variables are passed, if not, set defaults :

```
<?php
// Checks to see if $emailto is empty, if so, it will send to this default email address
if (empty($_GET['emailto'])) {
    $_GET['emailto'] = 'info@mysite.com';
}
?>

<?php
// Checks to see if $title is empty, if so, will default the the selected title "US"
if (empty($_GET['title'])) {
    $_GET['title'] = 'Us';
}
?>
```

Upon SUBMIT, the contact.php form strips code, checks validity, etc before submitting. I'm still feeling naked having them in the URL in this day and age of hackers and spambots.  If it is a horrible and unspeakable way to pass the variables, any thoughts on how to accomplish the same thing?  I would rather not have a drop down on the contact form for people to choose who to contact, but I suppose that's an option.   Ok.... be kind! ;)

Comment: @jeroen It is no more succeptable to spam than any other implementation; unless you were to implement CSRF into all links, and forms etc; which is unfeasible and unlikely to happen, then all requests can be a causation for spam.

Comment: @Bowersbros You're right, my comment is too broad and not specific to the question...

Answer (score 1):

Submit via post using Javascript instead of get. It's a much better way to send this sort of data than get.

```
function contact(title, to)
{
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('emailto', to + '@mysite.com');
    formdata.append('title', title);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('post', 'contact.php', false);
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this same thing, without plain-sight variables is to use the `data-` attributes in HTML5, and then couple that with jQuery.post using jQuery of course.

```
<a href="#" class="contact-user" data-user-email="jim@jimmy.com">Contact Jimmy!</a>
```

Then throw in some jQuery:

```
$('.contact-user').on('click', function(e){
    var userEmail = $(this).data('user-email');

    $.post('handle_contact.php', {
        userEmail: userEmail
    }, function(data) {
        // Do something with data
    }, 'json'); // JSON return for example
});
```

To answer your question, though, what you're doing is not considered *dangerous*, but it could lead to issues if you're not handling the variables properly. An attacker could easily pass in dangerous code and if you don't sanitize it correctly, you could be very vulnerable. However, this isn't unique to your case.